# Fill array within nested loops

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am trying to fill an array in two nested loops however for each second pPiece[] i want to give it a k attribute of 0 or 1 every second pPiece[] respectively

For example -

```
  pPieces[0] = new Piece(0,pcName,1);
  pPieces[1] = new Piece(1,pcName,1);
  pPieces[2] = new Piece(0,pcName,1);
  pPieces[3] = new Piece(1,pcName,1);
  etc....
```

What i have

```
private Piece pPieces[] = new Piece[8];

for(int j=0; j<pCount; j++) //pCount = 4
  {
      for(int k=0; k<pcCount; k++) //pcCount = 2
      {
          String pcName = "Piece " + (allocation());
          pPieces[j+k] = new Piece(k,pcName,1);
      }
  }
```

Doing it this way results in pPieces[] index being over written 4 times, i think. Is it possible to properly fill this array which should have 8 objects stored in it with every second 'k' equaling 0 or 1 respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your current solution is that `j+k` will get the same value multiple times during the two loops:

```
for(int j=0; j<pCount; j++) //pCount = 4
{
    for(int k=0; k<pcCount; k++) //pcCount = 2
    {
        String pcName = "Piece " + (allocation());
        pPieces[j+k] = new Piece(k,pcName,1);
    }
}
```

For example, when `j = 0` and `k = 1`, you will have `j + k = 1`. But you will also have that when `j = 1` and `k = 0`.

The problem comes from the fact that you're incrementing the variable `j` by steps of 1 when you should increment it by steps of `pcCount`; and the related issue is that `j` should go to `pCount*pcCount` and not `pCount` only.

```
for(int j=0; j<pCount*pcCount; j+=pcCount) //<--- j+=pcCount here, not j++
{
    for(int k=0; k<pcCount; k++)
    {
        String pcName = "Piece " + allocation();
        pPieces[j+k] = new Piece(k,pcName,1);
    }
}
```

As a side-note, consider using more descriptive variable names instead of `pCount` and `pcCount`.

Comment: i've done this and it's only filling my array with 2 Piece objects instead of 4. I made a loop to go through pPieces.length and print and only 2 spots were filled. I changed "(allocation());" to "(j+k));" btw

Comment: yes that got it to add 4 thank you. Both this answer and @Geeth Lochana's answers are correct. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Refactor your code as follows, The issues is  `pPieces[j+k] = new Piece(k,pcName,1);`

```
Your j+k => 0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4
```

Corrected Code

```
private Piece pPieces[] = new Piece[8];
int count=0;

for(int j=0; j<pCount; j++) //pCount = 4
  {
      for(int k=0; k<pcCount; k++) //pcCount = 2
      {
          String pcName = "Piece " + (allocation());
          pPieces[count++] = new Piece(k,pcName,1);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, j+k will be overlapping. But 2j+k does not.
You need to replace by :

private Piece pPieces[] = new Piece[8];

```
for(int j=0; j<pCount; j++) //pCount = 4
  {
      for(int k=0; k<pcCount; k++) //pcCount = 2
      {
          String pcName = "Piece " + (allocation());
          pPieces[2*j+k] = new Piece(k,pcName,1);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%` operator can be of use here:

```
private Piece pPieces[] = new Piece[8];

for(int j = 0; j < pPieces.length; j++) {
    String pcName = "Piece " + (allocation());
    pPieces[j] = new Piece(j % 2,pcName,1);
}
```

---

The `%` (modulus) operator returns the remainder of integer division.

e.g.

```
0 % 2 = 0
1 % 2 = 1
2 % 2 = 0
3 % 2 = 1
```

Creating an alternation of 1 and 0.

Comment: this is designed to always fill my pPieces[] array. I don't want that to happen. But good idea!

Comment: @danielb Wasn't that the goal? _"Is it possible to properly fill this array which should have 8 objects stored in it..."_

Comment: yes i would like it to be filled, but not unconditionally. Your idea is correct in the instance that I would always want it filled. Sorry, I dont think i explained it clearly enough

Comment: @danielb Oh!, well this is just an example. You could put the for loop inside a method, and call that method when the condition applies.